# filter in document library [me] does not work?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter

I have created a document library on my site.

Now i want only the user to be able to view the documents that he/she have placed in this library.

I thought i could use [Me]
But it does not work.

This is what i have done.
[image]

Comment: Does that translate to `Created by is equal to [Me] or Modified by is equal to [Me]`? If so, that should do it.

Comment: Found solution.  I had to translate ME to my language JAG (Swedish)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try translating [Me] to your language. 
If I'm right this is Swedish language, so try with: [Jag]